# iOS Publishing App via Apple Developer Invitation

Tags: ios, certificate

Hey guys I have to publish an App with a foreign Apple Account. I got the invitation and now I can download the Distribution Provisionig Profile. However I also need the valid signing identity - that means that I also have to create a Distribution Certificate but this option is disabled or I only can create a Development Certificate (like shown in the screenshot below).

Am I right that this Distribution Certificate has to be created by the Account Owner? What exactly does he have to do in order to get the available Distribution Provisioning Profile to work on my machine?

I Would be glad for some hints!

[image: Distribution Certificate Menu]

Comment: Yes, you are right! The distribution certificates must be created by account owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The account owner has to export both the distribution certificate and the private key and share them with you. You install them on your computer and everything should work.

Comment: the private key must be exported from the keychain as a .p12 file right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I think they can be both exported to one .p12 file.